# How to change custom post order ASC/DESC menu_order wise dynamically?

Tags: front-end, sort, menu-order

I have created custom post type in back end with sort menu_order post as you can see in the screenshot. http://prntscr.com/gacw95

In back end sorting ASCENDING/DESCENDING working fine.

But I need to Sort ASC/DESC on the front side also.

When I click on order tab in back end It will be sorting the post in back end but not in front end.

How can I sort the custom post in front side when change in the back end?

**Backend code**

```
<?php
// ptype_gallery Custom Post Type
add_action( 'init', 'ptype_gallery_post_type' );
function ptype_gallery_post_type() {
    register_post_type( 'ptype_gallery',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Gallery', 'theme' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Gallery', 'theme' ),
                'add_new' =>  __( 'Add New Gallery', 'theme' ),
                'add_new_item' =>  __( 'Add New Gallery', 'theme' ),
                'edit_item' =>  __( 'Edit Gallery', 'theme' ),
                'new_item' =>  __( 'New Gallery', 'theme' ),
                'all_items' =>  __( 'All Gallery', 'theme' ),
                'view_item' =>  __( 'View Gallery', 'theme' ),
                'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Gallery', 'theme' ),
                'not_found' =>   __( 'No Gallery found', 'theme' ),
                'not_found_in_trash' =>  __( 'No Gallery found in Trash', 'theme' ), 
                'parent_item_colon' => '',
                'menu_name' =>  __( 'Gallery', 'theme')
            ),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'menu_position' => 26,      
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'page-attributes', 'thumbnail', 'editor' ), 
        'rewrite'  => array( 'slug' => 'gallery', 'with_front' => true ),
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-format-gallery',  // Icon Path
        )
    );
}

// MetaBox
add_action( 'admin_init', 'ptype_gallery_register_meta_box' );
function ptype_gallery_register_meta_box()
{
    // Check if plugin is activated or included in theme
    if ( !class_exists( 'RW_Meta_Box' ) )
    return;
    $prefix = 'ptype_gallery_';
    $meta_box = array(
            'id' => 'gallery-settings',
            'title' => 'Photo Gallery',
            'pages' => array( 'ptype_gallery' ),
            'context' => 'normal',
            'priority' => 'core',
            'fields' => array(          
                    /*array(
                        'name' => 'Specifications',
                        'desc' => '',
                        'id' => $prefix . 'specs',
                        'type' => 'textarea',
                        'std' => '',
                        'rows' => '10'
                    ),*/

                    array(
                        'name' => 'Gallery Images',
                        'desc' => '',
                        'id' => $prefix . 'images',
                        'type' => 'image_advanced'
                    ),

                 )
            );
    new RW_Meta_Box( $meta_box );
}

// Add a new column for the order
function add_new_ptype_gallery_column($ptype_gallery_columns) {
  $ptype_gallery_columns['menu_order'] = "Order";
  return $ptype_gallery_columns;
}
add_action('manage_edit-ptype_gallery_columns', 'add_new_ptype_gallery_column');

// Render the column values
function show_order_column_gallery($name){
  global $post;

  switch ($name) {
    case 'menu_order':
      $order = $post->menu_order;
      echo $order;
      break;
   default:
      break;
   }
}
add_action('manage_ptype_gallery_posts_custom_column','show_order_column_gallery');

// Set the column to be sortable
function order_column_register_sortable_gallery($columns){
  $columns['menu_order'] = 'menu_order';
  return $columns;
}
add_filter('manage_edit-ptype_gallery_sortable_columns','order_column_register_sortable_gallery');
?>
```

**Front End code**

```
  Template Name: Photo Gallery Page Template

 */

get_header();
?>
<div id="main">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="container" class="fullwidth photo-gallery-section">
            <h2 class="pageTitle">
                <?php the_title(); ?>
            </h2>
            <?php
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'ptype_gallery', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'post_status' => 'publish'
            );
            // the query
            $the_query = new WP_Query($args);               
            ?>

            <?php if ($the_query->have_posts()) : ?>

                <!-- pagination here -->

                <!-- the loop -->
                <?php
                while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post();
                    $images = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'ptype_gallery_images');

                    if ($images) {
                        ?>
                        <h4 class="pageTitle">
                            <?php the_title(); ?>
                        </h4>
                        <div class="photogallery-section">
                            <?php
                            echo '<div class=""></div><div class="productImages row">';
                            foreach ($images as $image) {
                                $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image, 'product_thumb');
                                $img = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image, 'full');
                                $attachment = get_post($image);
                                ?>
                                <div class="grid2">
                                    <div class="productImgBx">
                                        <div class="productImg"><a data-fancybox="gallery" href="<?php echo $img[0]; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $thumb[0]; ?>"/></a></div>
                                        <div class="productImgTitle"><?php echo $attachment->post_content; ?></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <?php
                            }
                            echo '</div>';
                            ?>
                        </div>

                    <?php } endwhile; ?>
                <!-- end of the loop -->

                <!-- pagination here -->

                <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

            <?php else : ?>
                <p><?php _e('Sorry, no products found.'); ?></p>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

This is my page template with displaying custom post type on frontend but can not sorting as per the backend.

Please help me.

Thank you indvance.

Comment: sorting in backend is not related to sorting in frontend

Comment: I know, I already mentioned that I have code with admin side but I need front sorting when changing on backend side. Got it @inarilo

Answer (score 0):

You can hook [`pre_get_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) and use the [`order_by`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters) argument of `WP_Query`.
From a plugin or *functions.php* of active theme, something like the following (untested example):

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_post_type_sort', 10, 1);

function my_post_type_sort( $query ) {
     if ( is_admin || ! $query->is_main_query() ) {
        return;
     }
     if ( $query->get('post_type') !== 'name_of_post_type' ) {
        return;
     }
     $query->set('orderby', array( 'menu_order' => 'ASC') );

}
```

Comment: Hello @hwl, I have use this code and replace with my custom post name.
But it's not working for me.
I have also edit the code in my question please note that I need Sorting custom post in frontend not backend. Backend side already working fine.
But When I sort on backend, the posts dyanamically sort on frontend.
Thank you.

Comment: 1) What does "it's not working for me" mean? Is there some error? No error but no change? Where did you "use" this code? 2) In the backend, where is the value of the _Order_ column coming from and saved? Is this a custom `post_meta` key, perhaps?

Comment: Hello @hwl, I have added all the code frontend & backend.
Please check and understand the entire code.
Thank you.